# Anything Equivalent to MDI Windows in Mac OSX XCODE

Tags: macos, cocoa, jframe, mdi

I Just started to develop an app for Mac OSX and I need to make a window which contains another child windows like this:

[image]
[image]

In VB.NET is called MDI Window (Multiple Document Interface) and in Java is called JFrame if I'm not wrong, I need its equivalent in cocoa

thanks in advance for the support

Comment: Honestly, I don't recall OSX applications behaving this way.

Comment: if not what's the proper way to call them???

Comment: OSX doesn't restrict an application's document windows to an overall application window. Remember that OSX applications all use the menu bar at the very top of the screen, where as each Windows application has its own. You're looking at a different application paradigm under OSX.

Comment: If you really want this kind of behavior, then I recommend using a tabbed interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MDIs are not supported by Cocoa on the Mac. While some applications, such as many Java apps, do have them on the Mac, bringing them to the Mac breaks a lot of behaviors that Mac users are used to:

- They don't work well with multiple monitors
- They make it harder to compare documents
- They make it harder to drag and drop
- They take away space on the screen that would have been unused by your application and could be used for something more useful
- They break the ability to put multiple documents into full screen mode separately
- They effectively hide documents from view in Mission Control
- They force the user to manage the size and location of what is effectively your own app's "mini desktop" when they should be focused on their own work.

There may be other things that MDI's negatively affect as well.

I strongly suggest reading the [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) (or 'HIG' for short) to familiarize yourself with Mac UI fundamentals.

Mac users are picky about UIs and while they may not go out of their way to thank you for understanding Mac UI fundamentals, they will mob you with negative reviews for releasing something that feels less than a "true" Mac app.

Learn and design to the native UI language, it will be well worth it and you'll spend far less time fighting the OS and Cocoa.

Comment: thanks for your response it helps a lot to new Mac Developers, greetings

Comment: I could see mdi on mac just being top level windows linked to another top level window on the taskbar. Once you close the main top level window the other top level windows linked to it close. I also don't see any reason why the linked MDI children should have a icon in the taskbar.